# Multiple Filter Conditions on RetrieveSalesforceObjects

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to match against multiple values after the comparison operator?

I'm trying to filter against a title field where there could be a handful of correct titles, but I can't get it to work. Should I be wrapping in else if logic, you think?

for example:

```
set @records = retrievesalesforceobjects("User", "Name", "Title", "=", "Sr, Jr, Lead, Dev")
```

The records could be any of those, but I'm not retrieving any records when using all at once - only if I match against one of the records.

Is there an elegant way to pull in each of those titles for the respective records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only match one value per field and there is no `OR` clause available for use when you add additional fields to match on, so you’d have to use a separate retrieve call for each of the possible titles you want to match on and then use if/else statements to sort through the results.

> Additional API field name, comparison operator and value sets can be
> appended as arguments. However the function joins these additional
> sets using `and` clauses.

Source: https://ampscript.guide/retrievesalesforceobjects/

Comment: thank you, I got it to work by using IF statements. wish they would make it easier to add OR conditions in the future. thanks!